# Select from Row 1 to 27 in last used column

Tags: excel, vba, row

I have this code to select cell 1 from the last used column.

`.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select`

Now I want to select this cell 1 and 27 cells down to make a border.

How can i select those cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't select that cell, but rather `Set` a `Range()` object variable, then `Resize()` that object and add borders, for example:

```
Set cl = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
cl.Resize(27).BorderAround ColorIndex:=3, Weight:=xlThick
```

Comment: Thank you, worked great for what i need. Also thanks for the explanation and example

Comment: Is there also a way to use this code and add the horizontal lines in thin? Like: 
 BorderHorizontals ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThin ?

Comment: New questions get new posts @BrunoPereira. Don't forget to accept this answer if it has answered your initial quesiton.